# Use JavaScript to target nth column in table or nth cell of every table row

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am trying to target a specific column on a click event for a given table. I am having a hard time specifying my selection to every row or ideally, selecting an entire column of td elements of a specific index. What I have so far:

```
 sorter(d, i) {

        console.log(i);
        let n = i;
        let table = document.querySelector('tbody');
        let rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
        //let length = this.tableElements.length;

        let td = rows.cells[n];

        console.log(td);

    }
```

If I use: let td = rows[0].cells[n];
I get the selection that I want from a specific cell index for the first row as expected. How do I specify every row with this? I want to use this selection to sort the table.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate `rows` and return an array of values

```
let tds = Array.from(rows, row => row.cells[n]);
```

Comment: You could probably alternatively use `let tds = table.querySelectorAll("tr td:nth-child("+ i + 1 +")")`, depending on what `i` is, as `:nth-child()` pseudo class is 1-based.

Answer (score 0):

```
    sorter(d, i) {

            console.log(i);
            let n = i;
            let table = document.querySelector('tbody');
            let rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
            //let length = this.tableElements.length;
var td;
        for(l=0;l<length;l++){
             td = rows[l].cells[n];

            console.log(td);
    }
        }
```